# Definite inequality comparing a product of sums?

Tags: inequalities

I have a derivative that can be simplified to the following and I was wondering whether there are general results about the sign of this type of formula:

$$
\bigg( \sum_j k_j a_j b_j \bigg) \bigg(\sum_j k_j c_j d_j \bigg) - \bigg( \sum_j k_j a_j d_j \bigg) \bigg(\sum_j k_j c_j b_j \bigg) \lessgtr 0
$$
where $ a_j < c_j $ and $ b_j < d_j $.

Any help or references would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions are not enough to determine the sign of the lhs of your inequality. E.g., suppose that $k_j=1$, $c_j=a_j+1$, $d_j=b_j+1$, and $n=2$. Then the lhs of your inequality is $(a_1-a_2)(b_1-b_2)$, which can obviously be of any sign, depending on whether $a$ and $b$ are increasing or not.

Comment: A more general observation is that interchanging $b_j$ and $d_j$ for all $j$ changes the sign.  But I think the OP is asking for additional conditions on the values that have some known effect on the sign.  Monotonicity conditions could be an example.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay : I think the condition $b_j<d_j$ prevents the interchanging of $b_j$ and $d_j$. Your interpretation of the question may be right, concerning additional conditions. However, it seems to me there are too many degrees of freedom allowed here.